# Не показывается рекламный баннер admob (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, admob, ads

Пытаюсь добавить тестовый рекламный баннер в пустое приложение. Делаю все по инструкциям https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start и https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

Создал проект с Empty Activity и минимальным SDK версии Android 5.0. Сначала добавил строчку в build.gradle (Module:app) и нажал Sync Now

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.6.0'
```

Добавил метаданные с тестовым id приложения в манифест

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
```

В activity_main.xml вставил баннер, разместил его вверху

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="45dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Скопировал код со второго сайта и вставил в MainActivity.java, импортировал все классы

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView mAdView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Во вкладке дизайн баннер отображается, а когда запускаю эмулятор - его нет.

[image: Скриншот]

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Извиняюсь, возможно, вопрос уже заезженный, но я только учусь.

Comment: Простите, а зачем? Деньги вам платить не будут всё равно. Санкции

Comment: Но тестовый баннер не может не отображаться из-за санкций, ведь так? Или может?

Comment: А Бог его знает, может и нет